# for IEEE 802.11 communication packet are transmitted in form of bits then how other layers identifies their format

Tags: wifi, ieee

I am not getting how the bits will be differentiated at each level to identifies their own packets to be processed further.

I have tried various sources but didn't find something solid in response to this, can anyone help me with this.

Thankyou in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Each lower layer removes the header corresponding to that layer before sending it to upper layer. The header starts from the very first bit and each layer knows what is the length of it's header.

Comment: i am thankful for your response. But what if the number of bits it has taken considering as header are not the one which are for header ?

Comment: I could not get what you are trying to ask. What does "it" mean here. Do you mean "what if a layer, while processing header of a frame,  got the header length wrong?". If that is the case, please check the original answer again.